# 4NEC2 radials & grounds

Tags: grounding, antenna-modeling, counterpoise

Teaching myself 4NEC2 and have most of it under control, which is good.

Regarding radials & grounds, i've been learning the "rules" NEC(2) has, summarised below.

> 4.1. Free space.
>
> In the simulations in free space, logically there is no ground.
> Normally, the results will be similar to those one may find in the
> textbooks.
>
> 4.2. Perfect ground.
>
> The perfect ground consists of a perfect electrical conductor ground
> plane, without losses. It is a good option to make simulations
> omitting the losses of the ground, a task which may allow to evaluate
> those losses comparing the results with further simulations using more
> realistic ground types.
>
> The wires of a model can touch the perfect ground.
>
> 4.3. Fast ground.
>
> With the fast ground type, NEC-2 uses a method based on complex
> reflection coefficients.
>
> The wires of the model cannot touch the fast ground.
>
> In the case of the horizontal wires, it is necessary to observe a
> height over the ground of at least one tenth of the working wavelength
>
> [Ref.4,8]: Zs > (lambda / 10) for horizontal wires.
>
> 4.4. MININEC ground.
>
> The MININEC ground model assumes a perfect ground for the computation
> of the currents and changes to a dielectric ground for the computation
> of the far field patterns (ground without losses). With the MININEC
> ground, hybrid calculations designed for the first generation of less
> powerful computers are used.
>
> The vertical wires can touch the MININEC ground.
>
> The horizontal wires cannot touch the ground. They must be placed at a
> height over the ground of at least one fifth of the working
> wavelength:
>
> [Ref.4,8]: Zs > (lambda / 5) for horizontal wires over MININEC ground.
>
> If this rule is not observed, the simulations with NEC-2 will provide
> as a result erroneous impedances and anomalous high gains, especially
> for horizontal polarisation.
>
> 4.5. Sommerfeld-Norton (S-N) ground.
>
> The Sommerfeld-Norton (S-N) is the most precise ground model, with the
> highest computational cost and is the best method to simulate
> horizontal wires very close to the ground.
>
> Using the S-N ground it is important to take into account that both
> the vertical and the horizontal wires cannot touch ground.

It's nice to use "fast ground" and define radials in 4NEC2's ground-tab, but it wont be accurate having the vertical wire touch the ground in the model per NEC2's rules, i could use Sommerfield-Norton ground, which is more accurate, but i'd have to elevate the radials (ground plane), which doesn't match reality (this is for a 1/4wl ground-mounted monopole).

I could draw/define them in the geometry tab i guess, but it would be handy to use fast-ground if i could get reasonable accuracy, to leverage it drawing many radials in, with equal spacing (just a pain to do it manually, especially for large numbers of radials).

To achieve reasonable accuracy, is there any middle-ground (pun unintentional lol), or is it basically one or the other?

Comment: Actually we'd rather that you //would// list or summarize the NEC(2) ground types, for two reasons: 1) it makes the question easier to read, and 2) links rot.

Comment: Fair point rclocher3. Question updated.